# What is the binary difference between IPA coming from AppStore and those from XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

**Long story short:**

How can I debug an iPhone-App directly on the hardware (iPhone) in exactly the same version/binary as it would be distributed by AppStore without the need to wait for AppStore-Preview-Process?

**En detail:**

I detected strong differences with the behaviour of an MKMapView between a compiled IPA running on an iPhone using Developer Profile via XCode/USB-Cable and between the Version installed directly from an AppStore after the Distribution-To-AppStore-Process.

I will attach two significant Screenshots.

This is how the App launches the MKMapView on an iPhone via XCode/USB-Cable pointing to the current users location with a special region:

[image]

And this is how the same App launches on the same iPhone after installing the distributed version from the AppStore **without any code changes** to the previous one:

[image]

Here i will provide some Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:[self.mapView annotations]];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D noLocation;
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(noLocation, 6500, 6500);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
    [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:NO];

    mapView.delegate = self;

    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    theMapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.location.coordinate;
}
```

*Btw, just for your information: here occured another difference between an IPA running directly on the iPhone launched by XCode and the distributed Archive via AppStore. Without the Line "[self.mapView removeAnnotations:[self.mapView annotations]];" the App crashed directly after launch in the installed Version from AppStore, but not when running from XCode. This issue i ran into in a previous version and is not part of this question, just an addition to the main question*

**The main question is:**

Is it possible to debug an iPhone-App exactly the same way as it would be distributed by AppStore without the need to wait for AppStore-Preview-Process, and if yes, how?

Comment: In the past I've been advised by Apple to re-sign the final .app package with a provisioning profile that I can use to install the binary on my device.  Typically, this is set up with the Release scheme, and resigning can be done with [AppResigner](http://www.gorbster.net/blog/archives/273).

Comment: Thanks for your help, Hyperbole. How can i find the .app - package in the filesystem? Usually i use "Product => Archive => App Store Distribution". And how can i launch this .app-Package on an iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the app you run on your iphone via Xcode will be in `debug` mode, the one on the App Store is in `release` mode. If you use `preprocessors macro` (like `DEBUG`), this could change the behaviour of your app.

If you think this could be the problem, go in XCode, in `Product` > `Scheme` > `Edit Scheme`, select your project's target and change the `BuildConfiguration` to `Release`. You will see how your app run in release mode even if you run it from Xcode. It will be easier to debug the behaviour of your app.

Comment: Thank you very much! I get now the same behaviour as with the AppStore-version.

Answer (score 8):

The main difference here is just likely to be a release build versus a debug build. You've got:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D noLocation;
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(noLocation, 6500, 6500);
```

You don't set any initial value to `noLocation`. It's a raw `struct` so nobody else does either. It could have any value whatsoever. As a result `adjustedRegion` could be any region. No doubt it just happens to be something vaguely valid on your debug build and something completely nonsensical on your release build. Then probably `MKMapView` decides to show the entire earth if it can't make sense of the thing and when you shift the centre to the shops in your area it doesn't affect the zoom.

To fix, give `noLocation` a defined, valid value.